# 802.11 Authentication/Association and WPA/WPA2 authentication (Four-way handshake)

Tags: network, wireless, wpa2

So I have read that 802.11 standard requires stations and APs to go through the authentication and association before communication can take place. I also know that WPA/WPA2 has its own authentication method which involves a 4-way handshake to construct the PTK out of the PMK.

I am guessing these are two different authentications that happen separately ? I just want to understand the order of events. Is it correct to say that once the initial 802.11 Authentication and Association are finished then the WPA/WPA2 authentication mechanism starts?

Thanks

Comment: So WPA operates when the initial authentication is taking place before association? According to a source I have read it says otherwise https://kb.meraki.com/knowledge_base/80211-association-process-explained

Comment: My understanding is clients use WPA/WPA2 to perform authentication and association on 802.11 networks (802.11i).  For more details see http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/networking/wireless/0596001835/802dot11-framing-in-detail/wireless802dot11-chp-4-sect-4 and http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/networking/wireless/1587051540/securing-wlans-overview/ch01lev1sec5

Answer (score 1):

WPA2 is just a commercial name for a complete implementation of the 802.11i specification (WPA implemented only a part of it as a temporary measure against WEP weakness).

802.11i is an amendment to the original 802.11 specification, which means that it replaced several part from it, the original content becoming deprecated and a new revision of the 802.11 being edited.

More specifically, 802.11i introduces the concept of Robust Security Network Association (RSNA), and distinguishes between pre-RSNA security algorithms (WEP and 802.11 entity association) and RSNA security algorithms (the more secured algorithms allowed by WPA2).

Your hardware and software may offer pre-RSNA and RSNA security, usually as drop down menu allowing to select either WEP, WPA or WPA2. Your configuration here will define which algorithm you use, but **at a given time you will use only one of them, they are not cumulative and will not be used at the same time**.

For more information, 802.11i amendment [can be found here](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11i-2004.pdf) (as per the current subject you directly jump to the "Security" chapter), and all successive amendments have been merged in the reference [802.11 specification](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf) (including deprecation of TKIP, which after all was just a temporary solution designed for WPA).